# React - useState not updating correct values for the JSON value count in useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update the total count of each type of orders that are available before rendering it to UI. I am facing issue with the count not updating correctly for the particular key.

I have 3 small snippets of the code.

**Dummy JSON**

```
  export let orders = [
{
  id: "1000",
  dateTime: "Tue 13 Jun 11:52 AM",
  merchant: "RAJUGARI VINDU BOJANAM",
  customer: "Purnima Reddy",
  items: "3",
  total: "862.42",
  type: "Delivery",
  payment: "cod",
  status: "Completed",
  notes: "Good",
},
{
  id: "1001",
  dateTime: "Tue 13 Jun 11:52 AM",
  merchant: "RAJUGARI VINDU BOJANAM",
  customer: "Purnima Reddy",
  items: "3",
  total: "862.42",
  type: "Delivery",
  payment: "cod",
  status: "Completed",
  notes: "",
},
{
  id: "1002",
  dateTime: "Tue 13 Jun 11:52 AM",
  merchant: "RAJUGARI VINDU BOJANAM",
  customer: "Purnima Reddy",
  items: "3",
  total: "862.42",
  type: "Delivery",
  payment: "cod",
  status: "Pending",
  notes: "Something is better",
},
{
  id: "1003",
  dateTime: "Tue 13 Jun 11:52 AM",
  merchant: "RAJUGARI VINDU BOJANAM",
  customer: "Purnima Reddy",
  items: "3",
  total: "862.42",
  type: "Delivery",
  payment: "cod",
  status: "Cancelled",
  notes: "",
},
{
  id: "1004",
  dateTime: "Tue 13 Jun 11:52 AM",
  merchant: "RAJUGARI VINDU BOJANAM",
  customer: "Purnima Reddy",
  items: "3",
  total: "862.42",
  type: "Delivery",
  payment: "cod",
  status: "Collected",
  notes: "",
},
{
  id: "1005",
  dateTime: "Tue 13 Jun 11:52 AM",
  merchant: "RAJUGARI VINDU BOJANAM",
  customer: "Purnima Reddy",
  items: "3",
  total: "862.42",
  type: "Delivery",
  payment: "cod",
  status: "Ready",
  notes: "",
},
{
  id: "1006",
  dateTime: "Tue 13 Jun 11:52 AM",
  merchant: "RAJUGARI VINDU BOJANAM",
  customer: "Purnima Reddy",
  items: "3",
  total: "862.42",
  type: "Delivery",
  payment: "cod",
  status: "Accepted",
  notes: "almost",
},
{
  id: "1007",
  dateTime: "Tue 13 Jun 11:52 AM",
  merchant: "RAJUGARI VINDU BOJANAM",
  customer: "Purnima Reddy",
  items: "3",
  total: "862.42",
  type: "Delivery",
  payment: "cod",
  status: "Completed",
  notes: "almost",
},
];
```

**In Rendering JS File**

***useState Part***

```
  let [counts, setCounts] = useState({
  All: orders.length,
  Pending: 0,
  Accepted: 0,
  Ready: 0,
  Collected: 0,
  Completed: 0,
  Cancelled: 0,
});
```

***useEffect Part***

```
useEffect(() => {
for (let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
  let key = orders[i].status;
  let prevValue = counts[orders[0].status];
  setCounts((counts) => ({ ...counts, [key]: prevValue + 1 }));
}
}, []);
```

In useEffect I am trying to loop through the elements and store *keys* of *counts* in ***key*** variable. Storing *previous value* in ***prevValue***. While setting the value I am spreading it as well. Not sure why the output in the console is all 1 even if the count of some key is more like **"Completed"**

[image: Console Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using orders[0] for the previous value. Also you should really try to only call setCount once at the end of the loop, not every iteration. You're also overwriting setCount with the previous value for each iteration.

I'm assuming the `useEffect` hook is shortened, because as it's written it's not really needed to use useEffect, but this is how I would rewrite the relevant parts:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const newCounts = {
     // I assume you need to add to the previous counts based on your example.
     ...counts
  };
  for (const order of orders) {
    const key = order.status;
    newCounts[key]++;
  }
  setCounts(newCounts);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Evert for pointing out my mistakes.

After using the code provided it is getting correctly updated. One of the mistakes was very silly i.e orders[0]